# The Elementor does not work just loaded, when go to custom WordPress page

Tags: php, wordpress, digital-ocean, cloudflare, elementor

I try using Elementor for creating a WordPress website but I have this page when I open Elementor on the website.

[image]

I am using DigitalOcean droplets with Cloudflare.
the save mode is already enabled on Elementor and when disabled, the page needed ```safe mode is disabled`` and so on, and the Rocket Loader is already defined on Cloudflare but I don't know what is happened here. Any solution about it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using DigitalOcean droplets with Cloudflare. the save mode is
> already enabled on Elementor and when disabled, the page needed
> ```safe mode is disabled`` and so on, and the Rocket Loader is already
> defined on Cloudflare but I don't know what is happened here. Any
> solution about it.

I has similar issue with elementor when go custom wordpress, in my case the plugin have clash with the other plugin (builder), you can try to disable/enable related and try again. But doesn't rule out other issue such as networks, conflict theme/custom, etc

Answer (score 0):

Just we need to install `Really Simple SSL` plugin from Wordpress and then activated it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your server configuration is high.

This issue is generally due to low server configuration. Please make sure you have the following settings on your server:

```
max_execution_time = 600
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 48M
memory_limit = 600M
max_input_time = 300
max_input_vars = 10000
```